# Cython impementation for existing Python code

Tags: python, cython

I have a Python code that processes 1 million rows (3000 bytes) and loads into Oracle database..

The code does lot of edits on many fields before it loads into a database...The code is completely written in Python and it takes lot of processing time...

I want to know if we can speed up the process using Cython implementation...

If so, how can I convert my existing Python code to Cython...

What all the features supported in Cython and is it reliable to use?

Comment: You seem to have confused "Cython" and "CPython".

Comment: thanks..correctted it now..

Comment: Can you post some sample code (on a site like Pastebin if it doesn't fit here)? Also, check out PyPy. It's way faster than CPython, but it uses the same coding standards. Or RPython, which is a restricted subset of Python that can also be pretty fast.